# Else-if syntax error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

```
var to = ['user1', '@user2', 'user3@email.com']
```

The following codeset should keep 'user1' in the `to` array, remove the '@' from the start of '@user2', and move 'user3@email.com' to the `toEmail` array

Right now, `else if (toName[j] == '@') {` is logging 'syntax error'

```
var toEmail = [];
var pushToEmail;
for (i=0; i<to.length; i++) {
  var pushToEmail = false;
  var toName = to[i];
  for (j=0; j<toName.length; j++) {
    if (toName[0] == '@') {
      toName[0] = toName[0].replace(/@/g, ''); // remove '@''
    }
    console.log('toName[0] = ' + toName[0]);
    else if (toName[j] == '@') {
      pushToEmail = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (pushToEmail == true) {
    toEmail += to.splice(INDEX, 1)[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: This is *extremely* hard to read. You should remove the `console.log` lines if you want to make this easier for us to help you.

Comment: @meagar good point, updated accordingly

Comment: @meagar could you upvote this cleaned up question..stackoverflow is contending to block new questions because of this and another lengthy question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You can't just throw a `console.log` in the space **between** an `if` and an `else`. The `else` has to be attached to an `if` statement, you've tried to attach that `else` to a `console.log`.

Comment: Tested that originally, but it seemed not to matter.. anyways, thanks, appreciate that.. Am now getting this 'INDEX is not defined' error though..any suggestions?

Comment: Ask a new question. This kind of interactive one-on-one debugging isn't how Stack Overflow is deigned to work.